# Proof of the Chain Rule in not normed TVS

Tags: derivatives, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces, chain-rule

In Differentiable and Riemannian manifolds by Lang, the chain rule theorem for TVS is stated, but the proof is left as an exercise. I gave it a try, so I expose here my idea. In order to check if I am on the right track, or if there is something I am missing.

In the textbook, the definition of differentiable map is the following:

> **Def.** Let $E,F$ be two topological vector spaces and $U\subseteq E$ and open set, a function $f:U\rightarrow F$ is said to be differentiable at $x_0\in U$ if there exists a linear map $\lambda:E\rightarrow F$ such that if we let $$f(x_0+y)=f(x_0)+\lambda y+\psi(y) $$ for small $y$, then $\psi$ is tangent to $0$

First of all I want to express my discomfort with the phrase for small $y$, which seems pretty arbitrary, and really confuses me a bit. Secondly, by tangent to $0$ the author means that for any neighborhood $W$ of $0\in F$, there exists a neighborhood of $0\in E$ such that $$\psi(tV)\subseteq o(t)W $$ where $o$ is real valued function of a real variable such that $\text{lim}_{t\rightarrow 0}o(t)/t=0$

The main theorem is the classical one

> **Theorem:** If $f:U\rightarrow V$ is differentiable at $x_0\in U$ and $g:V\rightarrow W$ is differentiable at $f(x_0)$, then $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and 
>   $$(g\circ f)'(x_0)=g'(f(x_0))\circ f'(x_0) $$

I figured this must be analogous to the usual proof of the chain rule. So, here is my attempt of a proof:

*Proof:* We have that $$g'(f(x_0))y=g(f(x_0)+y)-g(f(x_0))-\psi_g(y)$$ by the definition of differentiablity (for small $y$, whatever that means). In particular, take $y=f'(x_0)z+\psi_f(z)$ for some small $z$, where $\psi_f$ is the tangent to $0$ map form the definition of differentiability of $f$. Our expression is now $$[g'(f(x_0))\circ f'(x_0)](z)+[g'(f(x_0))\circ \psi_f](z)= g(f(x_0+z))-g(f(x_0))-[\psi_g\circ f'(x_0)](z)-[\psi_g\circ \psi_f](z)$$
so it suffices to show that for the small $z$ the maps $g'(f(x_0))\circ \psi_f,\;\psi_g\circ f'(x_0)$ 
 and $ \psi_g\circ \psi_f$ are tangent to $0$, the last map is trivially tangent to $0$. But I am clueless about proving that other two are in fact tangent to $0$

Comment: TVS = Topological Vector Space(s) for ordinary mortals (no allusion to corona virus)

Comment: Also, I am not sure if I give the notation the correct interpretation. Is $tV=\{tv \mid v\in V \}$ ?

Comment: [Is $tV=\{tv|v\in V\}$ ?] yes indeed.

Comment: I think I understand where the problem is. The definition with 
$\phi(tV)\subseteq o(t)W$ 
leads to a dead-end because it amounts to ask that $\phi$ be locally constant. The reason is that $o(t)=t\epsilon(t)$ with $\lim_{t\to 0}\epsilon(t)=0$ but for $t\not=0$, we would have $\phi(V)\subseteq \epsilon(t)(W)$ which would lead to $\phi(V)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Of course, as the notation $tV$ is involved, I can elaborate the detailed proof of what I say on request, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there are difficulties in defining a correct 
differentiability notion in general TVS. I invite you to consider 
[Gateaux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative)
and [Differentiation in Fréchet spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_in_Fr%C3%A9chet_spaces)
and the paragraph ``Tame Fréchet spaces'' for the last one.

Bourbaki himself in his volume [*Differentiable and Analytic Manifolds*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277027/existence-proof-of-bourbaki-differentiable-and-analytic-maniolfds) constructs his theory on Banach spaces.

As far as Lang's book is concerned, you can see that after Proposition 3.1, he returns to Banach spaces *All topological vector spaces are assumed to be Banach spaces*, so there is no harm to comment your proof in this context.

Now, returning to your proof, I would not begin by a difference (because along the way, you will encounter cones for which the increase has to be positive).

Using your notations, we can write
$$
f(x_0+x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0).x+\psi_f(x)\mbox{ and }  
g(y_0+y)=g(y_0)+g'(y_0)y+\psi_g(y)
$$
the $\psi$ functions being in the little-o class (this time - hopefully - correctly defined) i.e. 
$$
\psi_f(x)=||x||.\epsilon_f(x)\mbox{ and }
\psi_g(y)=||y||.\epsilon_g(y)
$$
with $\lim_{h\to 0}\epsilon_i(h)=0$.

Then the proof follows classically (but I can give full details if requested).

Hope it helps.

**Note** Your two questions 
(this one and [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588787/is-the-product-of-a-linear-map-and-a-tangent-to-0-function-a-tangent-to-0-functi)) are based on the (yet very interesting) book [1], please find below an analysis of the contexts and reasons. 
**Framework**

  Chapter 1.2 (Topological vector spaces)
1. [First page] Spaces are Hausdorff and locally convex.

   [Next page] For this book, we assume from now on that all our topological vector
   spaces are Banach spaces.

**Linear approximation**

1. Chapter 1.3 _Derivatives and Composition of Maps_, S. Lang starts with an extension to general TVS of the notion of 
   [Linear approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_approximation) 
   as follows

   let $E,F$ be two TVS, he defines a function $\varphi$ from a neighbourhood of zero in $E$ to a neighbourhood of zero in $F$ to be tangent to $0$ if, for all neighbourhood $W$ of $0$ in 
   $F$, there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ in $E$ (I suppose $V\subset Dom(\varphi)$) such that, for small $t$ 
   $$
   \varphi(tV)\subset \psi(t)W 
   $$    
   where $\psi$ is some function in the $o(t)$ class (just below).

   he (re)defines, like Laudau, the $o(t)$ class, i.e. real functions of a real variable such that $\lim_{t\to 0}\psi(t)/t=0$. Note that such a function $\psi\in o(t)$ is assumed to vanish 
   at zero and can equivalently be written $\psi(t)=t\varepsilon(t)$ where 
   $\lim_{t\to 0}\varepsilon(t)=0$

This definition boils down to the classical one in case of Banach spaces.

[1] Serge Lang, *Differential and Riemannian Manifolds*, 
Graduate texts in mathematics (160), Springer (1995)

Comment: Yes, I get that in normed spaces, the proof is classical; the issue comes when trying to generalize the notion of differentiation in general TVS, I think that I at first did not grasp the intuitive meaning of the tangent to $0$ concept. But I think the proof goes as explained in my question, the final step follows from this question you answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588787/is-the-product-of-a-linear-map-and-a-tangent-to-0-function-a-tangent-to-0-functi

Comment: A similar argument can be used to prove the right-hand conjugation

Comment: OK, otherwise, I claim that there is a ig problem with the definition given by S. Lang forr the reason I gave above, do you agree ? or would you like details ?

Comment: At that time, Bourbaki (whom S. Lang was a member) was searching stable generalizations for infinite dimension. It is not without serious reasons that they retreated to $E$ a Banach and $F$ locally convex in their framework. So, for chain rule, you need $E,F$ Banach and $G$ locally convex. I claim that there is a big problem with the definition (TVS) given in Lang's book for the reason that this implies that $f$ is locally constant. Do you agree ? or would you like me to give complete details ? (this does not diminish the merits of this fine mathematician however).

Comment: I note that he returns to Banach spaces. But I do not see the problem of the definition. To be precise: I do not follow how the tangent to $0$ condition implies that $\phi$ is locally constant. Also, local convexity is always assumed, the only generalization that is tried here to be made is to not consider norm into the structure of a TVS.

Comment: [But I do not see the problem of the definition.]---> OK, I complete my answer

Comment: You are right, I tried to prove that $\varphi$ is locally constant but failed (of course, this is not the case, for instance $x\to x^2$ is $\mathbb{R}$) and edited my answer accordingly, the question that this tentative generalization boils down to the classical case in the Banach context has to be proved. [ the only generalization that is tried here to be made is to not consider norm into the structure of a TVS]---> I agree. Point taken (+1).

Comment: I believe that the proof of it boiling down to a Fréchet derivative goes somewhat like this: Consider the case $f:E\supseteq U \rightarrow E$ for simplicity, it suffices to show that if $\psi$ a tangent to $0$ map  implies that $\text{lim}_{h\to 0} \psi(h)/\Vert h \Vert = 0$, for this, let $\varepsilon>0$ and $W$ be the ball centered at $0$ with radius $\varepsilon$. Now choose some convex open neighborhood $W_\varepsilon$ of $0$ subset of $W$, there exists some  op. neigh. $V$ of $0$ such that $\psi(tV)\subseteq \phi(t)W_\varepsilon$. [Continues at the newt comment]...

Comment: We are now done. For instance, we have  $\psi(V)\subseteq t \phi(t) W_\varepsilon$.  We now have that $t\phi(t)\leq t$  for some open neighborhood of $0\in \mathbb{R}$ contained in $(-1,1)$, and since $W_\varepsilon$ is convex, we have that $t \phi(t) W_\varepsilon\subseteq t W_\varepsilon \subseteq W_\varepsilon$.

Comment: Yes, we are done, yesterday I wrote also the proof that "it boils down to the classical one in case of Banach spaces." So I edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for the interaction (+1)