# Is the product of a linear map and a tangent to 0 function a tangent to 0 function?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, topological-vector-spaces

Dealing with TVS I have encountered that in order to complete some proofs, it sufficed to show the exact same statement, so I was wonder if my proof of it is correct. First, some definitions.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  we will say that $f$ is $o(t)$ if $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t)}{t}=0 $$
If $E,F$ are topological vector spaces, a map $\phi:E\rightarrow F$ is said to be tangent to $0$ is for every open neighborhood of $0\in F$, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $0\in E$ and some $f$ which is $o(t)$ such that $$\phi(tV)\subseteq f(t)W $$
Now, is the following statement true?

> Let $A$ be a continuous linear map from $E$ onto $F$ and $\phi:G\rightarrow E$ be a tangent to $0$ function, then $A\circ \phi$ is a tangent to $0$ map.

Here is my attempt of a proof:

*Proof:* Let $W$ be an open neighborhood of $0\in F$, since $A$ is linear and continuous, then $A^{-1}(W)$ is an open neighborhood of $0\in E$. Let $V$ be an open neighborhood of $0\in G$ such that $$\phi(tV)\subseteq o(t)A^{-1}(W)  $$ Apply $A$ to both sets and use linearity of $A$ to obtain 
$$(A\circ \phi)(tV)\subseteq o(t)W \quad  \blacksquare$$ 
Is this reasoning correct? I cannot help thinking that there is something I am missing.

Comment: [there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $0\in E$ such that $\phi(tV)\subseteq o(t)W $]---> did you mean [there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $0\in E$ and some $f$ which is $o(t)$ such that $\phi(tV)\subseteq f(t)W $] ?

Comment: Yes. I have the understanding that this abbreviation is usual. I think you can actually write $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)/x=0$ as $g(x)=o(x)$

Comment: This abbreviation is usual ---> I know this, but for reasoning and proofs, it is known as loose because it leads to contradictions , see  Dieudonné's (and many mathematicians) warnings and we must fix together your quantification (how heavy it may seem at first sight) "it exists ..." what exists really ? Tell me if I introduce errors.

Comment: Okay, perfect. Do you mean Dieudonné's Theorem? Also, I believe that it does not changes the argument in this proof. Do you see any mistake?

Comment: [Do you see any mistake?] Not at the level of ideas, your argument is correct, but the quantification must be made more precise, IMHO. [Do you mean Dieudonné's Theorem?]---> No, it is in one of his texts, I'll try to retreive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is essentially correct, now that objects are clearly identified, I would write it as follows

> Let $W$ be an open neighborhood of $0\in F$, since $A$ is continuous, $A^{-1}(W)$ is an open neighborhood of $0\in E$. Let $V$ be an open neighborhood of $0\in G$ and $f$ (of the $o(t)$ class) such that 
>   $$
> \phi(tV)\subseteq f(t)A^{-1}(W)  
> $$ 
>   Apply $A$ to both sets and use linearity of $A$ to obtain 
>   $$
> (A\circ \phi)(tV)\subseteq f(t)W \quad  \blacksquare
> $$

Hope it helps.